# API return failed using webrequest

Tags: .net, json, vb.net, api

I trying to connect an api in my application, this connection works before but now stopped.

If i use any browser or postman application the result is correct, but when i use a webrequest, webclient or any method in Visual Studio i received a timeout error.

I put the User Agent, set timeout, use ssl and the result is the same every time.

The end points tested is:

https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarkets

https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/?limit=1

When i use a site to test like a google this response works.

Any idea?

Update using WebRequestHelper

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Security
Imports System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates
Imports System.Text

Public Class WebRequestHelper
    Private m_ResponseUri As Uri
    Private m_StatusCode As HttpStatusCode
    Private m_StatusDescription As String
    Private m_ContentSize As Long
    Private m_WebException As WebExceptionStatus
    Public Property SiteCookies As CookieContainer
    Public Property UserAgent As String = "Mozilla / 5.0(Windows NT 6.1; WOW32; Trident / 7.0; rv: 11.0) like Gecko"
    Public Property Timeout As Integer = 30000
    Public ReadOnly Property ContentSize As Long
        Get
            Return m_ContentSize
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property ResponseUri As Uri
        Get
            Return m_ResponseUri
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property StatusCode As Integer
        Get
            Return m_StatusCode
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property StatusDescription As String
        Get
            Return m_StatusDescription
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property WebException As Integer
        Get
            Return m_WebException
        End Get
    End Property


    Sub New()
        SiteCookies = New CookieContainer()
    End Sub

    Public Function GetSiteResponse(ByVal siteUri As Uri) As String
        Dim response As String = String.Empty

        ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 50
        Dim maxFWValue As SecurityProtocolType = System.Enum.GetValues(GetType(SecurityProtocolType)).OfType(Of SecurityProtocolType)().Max()
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 Or SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 Or maxFWValue
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = AddressOf TlsValidationCallback

        Dim Http As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.CreateHttp(siteUri.ToString)
        With Http
            .Accept = "ext/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"
            .AllowAutoRedirect = True
            .AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip Or DecompressionMethods.Deflate
            .CookieContainer = Me.SiteCookies
            .Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip, deflate")
            .Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage, "en-US,en;q=0.7")
            .Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.CacheControl, "no-cache")
            .KeepAlive = True
            .MaximumAutomaticRedirections = 50
            .ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = False
            .ServicePoint.MaxIdleTime = Me.Timeout
            .Timeout = Me.Timeout
            .UserAgent = Me.UserAgent
        End With

        Try
            Using webResponse As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(Http.GetResponse, HttpWebResponse)
                Me.m_ResponseUri = webResponse.ResponseUri
                Me.m_StatusCode = webResponse.StatusCode
                Me.m_StatusDescription = webResponse.StatusDescription
                Dim contentLength As String = webResponse.Headers.Get("Content-Length")
                Me.m_ContentSize = If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(contentLength), 0, Convert.ToInt64(contentLength))

                Using responseStream As Stream = webResponse.GetResponseStream()
                    If webResponse.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK Then
                        Dim reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.Default)
                        Me.m_ContentSize = webResponse.ContentLength
                        response = reader.ReadToEnd()
                        Me.m_ContentSize = If(Me.m_ContentSize = -1, response.Length, Me.m_ContentSize)
                    End If
                End Using
            End Using
        Catch exW As WebException
            If exW.Response IsNot Nothing Then
                Me.m_StatusCode = CType(exW.Response, HttpWebResponse).StatusCode
            End If
            Me.m_StatusDescription = "WebException: " & exW.Message
            Me.m_WebException = exW.Status
        End Try
        Return response
    End Function

    Private Function TlsValidationCallback(sender As Object, CACert As X509Certificate, CAChain As X509Chain, SslPolicyErrors As SslPolicyErrors) As Boolean
        If SslPolicyErrors = SslPolicyErrors.None Then Return True
        Dim Certificate As New X509Certificate2(CACert)

        CAChain.Build(Certificate)
        For Each CACStatus As X509ChainStatus In CAChain.ChainStatus
            If (CACStatus.Status <> X509ChainStatusFlags.NoError) And
                (CACStatus.Status <> X509ChainStatusFlags.UntrustedRoot) Then
                Return False
            End If
        Next
        Return True
    End Function

End Class
```

And use this to call the class

```
Dim url As String = "https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarkets"
    Dim uri As New Uri(url)
    Dim wr As New WebRequestHelper
    Dim resp = wr.GetSiteResponse(uri)
```

Comment: Both APIs return correct results without problems. Take [the code I posted yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55584674/7444103) (for almost the same reason). I tested both with that. Read the notes. Both your sites require the Server Certificate validation callback (pretty common in TLS handshakes). Using HttpClient instead of WebRequest, you'ld need even less code. With HttpClient and .Net Framework 4.7.2+, almost none.

Comment: Sorry for delay Jimi, i try your solution but i have timemout response again, i use

        Dim url As String = "https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarkets"
        Dim uri As New Uri(url)
        Dim wr As New WebRequestHelper
        Dim resp = wr.GetSiteResponse(uri)

Comment: Did you implement the WebRequest exactly as it is in the code  I linked? I can't get it to fail. [This is a recording](https://imgur.com/A3YArMc) of the procedure using that exact code while debugging.

Comment: Yes Jimi, i used the same code (i paste the version in the question). It is very strange, i use the VS community 2019.

Comment: It's the Framework version and the System version that matter. That code is tested using FW 4.7.2. Is the `TlsValidationCallback` hit while debugging? Do you have a Proxy in between? Also, try it with just `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12`, commenting out the existing setting (maybe you have `TLS1.3` in your system and it's trying to negotiate it, the server accepts it and WebRequest doesn't know what to do after.).

Comment: I don´t use proxy, my target fW also is 4.7.2, i don´t have tls1.3, in the list option have ssl, systemdefault, tls, tls, tls11 and tls12. My previous code works fine before. In debug for TlsValidationCallBack i have an error BC30657: '"ToPointer" has a return type that is not supported or parameter types that are not supported.

Comment: [VB - IntPtr: error BC30657: 'ToPointer' has a return type that is not supported](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/491378/vb-intptr-error-bc30657-topointer-has-a-return-typ.html). VS 2019 issue. You can patch it yourself. I don't see where anything is assigned an IntPtr here, though.

Comment: Unless is `AddressOf` that causes the issue. Try with a Lambda and just return true (in 3 lines): `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = Function(s, CA, CAC, pol) Return True End Function`

Comment: Thank you again Jimi, i try lambda function but return the same result, the GetSiteResponse function enter in catch with the request timeout message , in the line  using webresponse as httpwebresponse = directcast(http.getresponse,httpwebresponse) . I try another https page and the function works (work with direct webresponse without this function), but in two url´s from the question not.

Comment: Weird. Anyway, since there are actually issues with VS 2019 (it's a preview release after all, plus I have never used a community edition, so I really can't say what may be missing), you can always use VS 2017, which is perfectly working. The two versions can live in the same machine without problems.

Comment: Hello Jimi, i used the application in another network and this work. Maybe my provider blocked these requests because i use many requests for minute. Can i change the webrequest port to test this? In browser and postman works, i imagine because use browser port.

Comment: [ServicePoint.BindIPEndPointDelegate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepoint.bindipendpointdelegate) . You just need a callback that returns a new `IPEndPoint`, where you specify the address (or `IpAddress.Any`) and the port number.

Comment: i used an uri object to connection and get the port number for this request 443.I called to my provider and this bloqued for requests. How i can make a connection using a browser and not using the application? Any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of how I connect to API.

First, create APIJSONViewModel based on your JSON result to store value of id, name, symbol, rank, price_usd, price_btc and etc..

```
        Dim limitnumber as integer = 1
        Dim apiurl As String = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com" 'base url
        Dim apirequesturi As String = "/v1/ticker/?limit=" & limitnumber 'request uri

        Dim resultresponse As List(Of APIJSONViewModel) = New List(Of APIJSONViewModel)

        Try
            Using client As HttpClient = New HttpClient

                ' set url
                client.BaseAddress = New Uri(apiurl)

                ' set json
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear()
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(New MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"))

                ' post model as json
                Dim response As HttpResponseMessage = Await client.GetAsync(apirequesturi)

                If response.IsSuccessStatusCode Then

                    ' result get!
                    resultresponse = Await response.Content.ReadAsAsync(Of List(Of APIJSONViewModel))()

                Else
                    r.Errors.Add(response.ReasonPhrase)
                End If

            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            r.Errors.Add(ex.Message)
        End Try
```